# how to send parameters to html file from pure javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This in a synopsis of my javascript file:

**foo.js**

```
function bar()
{      
      ... //to this point I have 2 variables area and city
      var popup = "<h5>Area:"+ area+"<BR>City: "+city+"</h5>"
      ...
}
```

I wish to 'import' a html file and send the parameters **area** and **city** instead of hard coding the popup. In other words I wish to do something like this pseudocode:

```
function bar()
{      
      ... //
      var html = load('./my_html.html', args=[area,city]); 
}
```

why this approach? because I need to call the my_html from different places and I wish to style the result nicely with css.

Comment: Maybe creating a function `"const dynamic = (a,c) => <h5>Area:"+ a+"<br>City: "+c+"</h5>"`

Comment: Typically you would use query string parameters, eg `\`my_html.html?area=${area}&city=${city}\`` but how were you planning on incorporating those parameters within `my_html.html`?

Comment: There are so many ways for doing just that, so.. what have you tried that was not successful?